# Log4j does not write into file and cannot disable spring log

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following issue:

I have an enviroment with apache tomcat 7.0.72 and I have three logs, cmfront, cmback and catalina.out.

The configuration of both (cmfront and cmback) is the same, cmfront:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=OFF

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/CmFront.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.CmFront=INFO,file,stdout
```

and cmback:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=OFF

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/CmBack.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.CmBack=INFO,file,stdout
log4j.logger.o=OFF
```

Nevertheless, when I deploy cmfront war, I deploy without any problem, but when I try whit cmback, my file does not write anyhting and also has the following logging lines:

```
16:08:28.768 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
16:08:28.768 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
```

And a lot of this kind of lines, my question is why in one war the logging properties works and does not print o.s.... debug lines, and by another hand the logs does not is written and also print a lot of debug lines if the configuration is the same?

Answer (score 0):

the properties are not application specific but spring related properties

if you have configured any spring bean related to mbean or any other , i think you can ignore those as long as the application is not affecting.

As far as the logging,

try the below 
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file,stdout

y r u setting root logger off, as you are not having any specific logger defined like com.****.com all your logs should go through the root logger.

For logs to work you should enable the root logger.

This is my guess might not be exact answer